# Using OR clause inside of find()

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I need to fetch a single row from database table using DBIx::Class when one of the two descriptor columns is like a provided data.

My SQL select looks like this:

```
select id from products where (code = 'VALUE' or description like '%VALUE%')
```

The table has unique constraint what ensures me that only one row exists for the VALUE.

How can I formulate this SQL using DBIx::Class?

The following code returns me the value **1** but not the correct data:

```
my $param = 'VALUE';
my $res = $c->stash->{products_rs}->search(
    -or => [
        { code => { '=', $param } },{ description => { 'like', '%'.$param.'%' } }
    ],
);
```

I should use the **find** method to return a single row but then I can not use the **-or** clause.

Any suggestion?

---

Hi, I am back. I decided to create myself the classes. First the schema class:

```
package prod::Schema;
use utf8;
use Moose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;
extends 'DBIx::Class::Schema';
__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces(
    default_resultset_class => 'ResultSet',
);
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable(inline_constructor => 0);
1;
```

I am using a base Result class for my table:

```
package prod::Schema::Result;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base qw( DBIx::Class::Core );
__PACKAGE__->load_components(
    "InflateColumn::DateTime", 
    "TimeStamp", 
    "EncodedColumn"
);
1;
```

Each table then uses a ResultSet base class:

```
package prod::Schema::ResultSet;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base qw( DBIx::Class::ResultSet );
__PACKAGE__->load_components('Helper::ResultSet::OneRow');
1;
```

and the Product class itself:

```
package prod::Schema::Result::Products;
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;
extends 'prod::Schema::Result';
__PACKAGE__->table("prod.products");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns("id",  {
    data_type => "uuid",
    default_value => \"uuid_generate_v4()",
    is_nullable => 0,
    size => 16,
}, "code", {
    data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 0, size => 2
}, "name", {
    data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 0, size => 128 },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("id");
__PACKAGE__->add_unique_constraint("uk_products_code", ["code"]);
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

The application uses this model class:

```
package prod::Model::DB_T;
use strict;
use base 'Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema';
__PACKAGE__->config(
    schema_class => 'prod::Schema',
    connect_info => {
        dsn => 'dbi:Pg:dbname=p12;host=localhost',
        user => 'username',
        password => 'password',
        AutoCommit => q{1},
    }
);
1;
```

The Root is this:

```
package prod::Controller::Root;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use Data::Dumper;
BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller' }
__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => '');
sub index :Path :Args(0) {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    my $Products = $c->model('DB_T::Products');
    my $product = $Products->search(
        -or => [
        { code => { '=', 'x' } },{ name => { 'like', '%'.'X'.'%' } }
        ],
    )->one_row;
    my $str = ''.$product->name;
    $c->response->body('product: '.$str);
}
sub default :Path {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    $c->response->body('Page not found');
    $c->response->status(404);
}
sub end : ActionClass('RenderView') {}
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

Now, I am using this **one_row** from that helper class, I do get the wanted result but the SQL statement remains open till I shutdown the application.

@Alexander Hartmaier you said that I should avoid this. But how? What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Just use `my ($res) = ...->search(...);` or `->search(...)->slice(1)`

Comment: Or `my $res = ...->search(...)->first;`

Comment: I tested each of the mentioned solutions and they are working. I will use the first one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Either by using the `one_row` method from the highly recommended [DBIx::Class::Helper](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Helper::ResultSet::OneRow) distribution or by copying its code.

`first` shouldn't be used because it keeps the database statement handle open.

Comment: Alexander, you are right. I checked the DB and I can see my statement. It is still open. That means, I have to add a new ResultSet class, extended with this **one_row**, what uses the generated Result class. Correct? The Result class was generated by Catalyst.

Comment: I have a base class for both all Result and ResultSet classes where I load all components etc. The base Result class sets the base ResultSet class which I override in those Result classes that have a specific ResultSet class. I'd recomment to load Helper instead of implementing it yourself because basically everything in there is DBIC best practise.

Comment: Could sketch such a class pair for a simple test table?